# .class file doesn't show the call to parent's constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I was trying to understand constructors in java. I read that if I don't provide a constructor in my java file, compiler will insert one for me (the default no-args one). I wrote a simple java file ConstructorTest.java as below.

```
public class ConstructorTest{
}
```

I then compiled it and using Cavaj, I could see the class file content as shown below.

```
public class ConstructorTest
{
    public ConstructorTest()
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't see the same happening for below statement, "If you type in your own constructor and do not type in the call to `super()` or `this()`, the compiler will insert a no-arg call to `super()`, as the very first statement in the constructor (excerpt from `ORACLE OCA/OCP` Java 7 Study Guide)".

My java file:

```
public class ConstructorChild extends ConstructorTest{

public ConstructorChild(){

}

}
```

My class file:

```
public class ConstructorChild extends ConstructorTest
{

    public ConstructorChild()
    {
    }
}
```

Why the call to `super()` is not inserted by compiler while compiling? Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You should tell us how you "read" the `.class` file

Comment: What you showed is not a .class file, it's another Java source file. Can you be clearer about what you're asking?

Comment: Hi @ErwinBolwidt,  when I mentioned class file, it was the content I could see in the .class file, when opened with Cavaj. My question was why compiler did not insert  "super()" as the first line in the compiled file, when I myself provided a constructor in the java file, as shown in the second example.

Comment: Hi @RC., I used Cavaj(one of the free java decompilers) to open the .class file.

Comment: @Chetan then the answer is simple: because Cavaj doesn't show the implicit call to `super()`, because it's optional. It's optional, because the compiler inserts it automatically. If you really want to see what's going on, you need to use `javap` and look at the bytecode (for which you need to research bytecode a bit)

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBolwidt, did a javap -c ConstructorChild.class in cmd and got this,  public class ConstructorChild extends ConstructorTest{
Public ConstructorChild();
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: return                                                                                                       I can understand that Object class's initialization block is called,  but shouldn't it call ConstructorTest class's init block first, before calling Object's constructor, or may be I didn't understand the bytecode properly.

Comment: I did the same and got `public class com.foo.bar.ConstructorChild extends com.foo.bar.ConstructorTest {
  public com.foo.bar.ConstructorChild();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method com/foo/bar/ConstructorTest."<init>":()V
       4: return        
}`

Answer (score 0):

Erwin Bolwidt is right. By the way, constructors in java byte code are always named `<init>`, while static blocks call themselves `<clinit>`. Also note that the latter can appear more than once and the JVM will call all of them in order of appearance on loading the class.